# DotNetCore 1.0 MVC how to automatically redirect to a single domain in live

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have multiple domains for a website:

http://example.com

http://www.example.com

http://www.example.co.uk

In production, I want the primary domain to be http://www.example.com and for all other associated domains to be automatically redirected to the primary.

Historically I would've done this with URLRewrite, however I'm led to believe that doesn't exist in DotNetCore.

So... how would I do this?

Also, I don't want this to affect development environments.

Comment: or you can just do it in IIS setting

Comment: @Steve how do I do this in IIS setting?

Comment: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @Steve - I did mention this in the question - I'm under the impression that this isn't available in DotNetCore 1.0?

Comment: IIS doesn't care what framework you use. Its the webhost (big daddy).  So if you use IIS it will be available there

Comment: Ok, fair point. So I probably should've mentioned this earlier - I'm hosting in Azure. I don't think you can get to IIS settings there?

Comment: if you are hosting on Azure VM then you DO have access to IIS settings. If not then http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx

Comment: It's Azure app services, sorry. The link you sent references URL rewriting within web.config which won't work. I suppose I could write a HttpModule for the time being but that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: why wouldn't web.config work? Your web application would contain a web.config alreay so is just matter of modifying it before uploading it onto azure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer that works with DotNetCore 1.0 (also forces https)

`Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Other configuration code here...

    if (env.IsProduction())
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Host != new HostString("www.example.com"))
            {
                var withDomain = "https://www.example.com" + context.Request.Path;
                context.Response.Redirect(withDomain);
            }
            else if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
            {
                var withHttps = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .net core 6:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();

    var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .Add(RewriteRules.ReDirectRequestsToOneHost);

    app.UseRewriter(options);
}


public class RewriteRules
{
    public static void ReDirectRequestsToOneHost(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Host != new HostString("www.example.com"))
        {
            var redirect = $"{request.Scheme}://www.example.com{request.Path}";
        
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirect);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use URLRewrite in .NET Core - just download ASP.NET Core 1.1 Preview 1. And then you will be able to do:

```
public class Startup {

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("(.*)/$", "$1")                    // Redirect using a regular expression
            .AddRewrite(@"app/(\d+)", "app?id=$1", skipRemainingRules: false) // Rewrite based on a Regular expression
            .AddRedirectToHttps(302, 5001)                  // Redirect to a different port and use HTTPS
            .AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "UrlRewrite.xml")        // Use IIS UrlRewriter rules to configure
            .AddApacheModRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "Rewrite.txt");       // Use Apache mod_rewrite rules to configure

        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }   
}
```

To update an existing project to ASP.NET Core 1.1 Preview 1 you will need to do the following:

- Download and install the updated .NET Core 1.1 Prevew 1 SDK
- Follow the instructions on the .NET Core 1.1 Preview 1 announcement to update your project to use .NET Core 1.1 Preview 1
- Update your ASP.NET Core packages dependencies to use the new 1.1.0-preview1 versions

More info here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/

Comment: I'm not using preview versions as this will be a production system.

Comment: .NET Core 1.0 is final? It's just missing the tooling?

Comment: @JamesLaw nope....   .NET Core 1.0 is just like Widows Preview. "Use it at your own risk"

Comment: This is just the code from the announcement. It doesn't solve the question.